# How to suppress red 500 error logs from a successful React Testing Library test in the console?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-testing-library, http-status-code-500, mockserver

I have the following successful test, which expects a 500 error:

```
  it('shows the error state', async () => {
    server.use(
      rest.get(get(), async (req, res, ctx) => {
        return res(ctx.status(500), ctx.json(buildEeRestErrorResponse('user', '500')));
      })
    );

    renderForTests(<Page />);
    const welcomeHeading = await screen.findByRole('heading', { level: 1 });

    // This test passes
    expect(welcomeHeading.textContent).toEqual('Welcome');
  });
```

The problem is that I see this red error log in the console when I run all of my tests:
[image]

Does anyone know how to suppress this scary looking error log? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppressing error logs during a unit test may be a simple as adding [jest-mock-console](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-console) to your project's dev dependencies.

```
npm install --save-dev jest-mock-console
```

Example Usage:

```
import mockConsole from 'jest-mock-console';

let restoreConsole;
beforeEach(() => {
  restoreConsole = mockConsole();
});

afterEach(() => {
  restoreConsole();
});

...

it('shows the error state', async () => {
  server.use(
    rest.get(get(), async (req, res, ctx) => {
      return res(ctx.status(500), ctx.json(buildEeRestErrorResponse('user', '500')));
    })
  );

  renderForTests(<Page />);
  const welcomeHeading = await screen.findByRole('heading', { level: 1 });

  // This test passes
  expect(welcomeHeading.textContent).toEqual('Welcome');
});

...
```

Comment: This is a cool package, thank you! Turns out I resolved my issue by mocking the `console.error` function above the `server.use` call like this: `console.error = jest.fn();`

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy Sure, that may also work. Don't forget to unmock when the tests complete.

Comment: How would I do that in this case?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy Probably something like `const consoleError = console.error;`, then your mock `console.error = jest.fn()`, then to restore `console.error = consoleError;`. Does this make sense?

Comment: I see, thanks! I should unmock after the expect in that test? Just to better understand, what are the repercussions of not unmocking?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy After the `expect` in a single test is fine, especially if you are only mocking it on a per-test basis. The repercussions of not unmocking it is that you mock it for all tests that run after this test, which might not be ideal. For example, if you made some changes in code that *did* start throwing lots of console errors.... but you won't see them in your tests and so might not be alerted to a problem until later (*hopefully before the code ships to production*).